# iOS Touch ID no password button wanted

Tags: ios, touch-id

Touch ID presents two buttons in its view, “Enter Password” and “Cancel” and I can’t find documentation on how to ask for fingerprints only, apps like Withings can successfully do it, asking only for fingerprints without the password button (just the cancel one).

How they can make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply set the   `myContext.localizedFallbackTitle` to an empty string

```
LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
myContext.localizedFallbackTitle = @"";
NSError *authError = nil;
NSString *myReasonString = @"Authentication required";
```